# Convert Decimals to Point (Longitude, Latitude) using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, geolocation, sql-update

Looked for this everywhere.  Can't find good answers.

My goal is to build a Long, Lat database for the zip codes in the USA.  Eventually, I may use Google Maps to update this, but we dont need any other data, at this time.

Using this data and MySQL, I'm trying to create a table with proper data.

https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666

I added the table to PHP My Admin with zipcode, longitude, latitude, and geo_point

Longitude, Latitude is DECIMAL(11, 6)
geo_point is POINT format.

```
CREATE TABLE `obe_zipcodes` (
  `zipcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
  `geo_point` point DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
COMMIT;
```

None of these work to convert the generic Decimals to Points, and give generic syntax errors

```
UPDATE obe_zipcodes SET geo_point=w2.longitude FROM obe_zipcodes, obe_zipcodes w2 WHERE obe_zipcodes.zipcode = w2.zipcode

UPDATE obe_zipcodes SET geo_point=POINT(w2.longitude, w2.latitude) FROM obe_zipcodes w1, obe_zipcodes w2 WHERE w1.zipcode = w2.zipcode
```

Answer (score 0):

It was easier then I thought,

```
UPDATE obe_zipcodes SET geo_point = POINT(latitude, longitude)
```